# Navigation setViewControllers not working

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I have a problem about UINavigation set viewcontrollers.
I already set viewcontrollers to UINavigation, but the result count also 1.
What's wrong about my code?
Thanks.

```
let mainSB = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

guard let ivc = mainSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: VC_InboxViewController) as? InboxViewController else { return }
guard let imdvc = mainSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: VC_InboxMessageDetailVC) as? InboxMessageDetailVC else { return }
guard let tabVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? TabbarVC else { return }
guard let naviVC: UINavigationController = tabVC.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController else { return }

var newsVCs: [UIViewController] = naviVC.viewControllers
newsVCs.append(ivc)
            
print("===) 1 newsVC.count : \(newsVCs.count)")
newsVCs.forEach { vc in
     print("===) 2 newsVC = \(vc)")
}

print("===) 3 naviVC.viewControllers.count : \(naviVC.viewControllers.count)")
print("===) 4 newsVC.count : \(newsVCs.count)")

naviVC.viewControllers = newsVCs //Problem here: set newsVCs not work!!!!!!
//naviVC.setViewControllers(newsVCs, animated: false)
            
print("===) 5 naviVC.viewControllers.count : \(naviVC.viewControllers.count)")
naviVC.viewControllers.forEach { vc in
    print("===) 6 vcvc: \(vc)")
}
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your setup in a plain playground, and it seems to just work and update the array correctly. Is there any other code you left out or maybe it's a storyboard only issue:

```swift
let inboxViewController = UIViewController()
let inboxMessageDetailViewController = UIViewController()
let tabVC = UITabBarController()
let mainViewController = UIViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
tabVC.viewControllers = [navigationController]

var newsViewControllers: [UIViewController] = navigationController.viewControllers
newsViewControllers.append(inboxViewController)
            
print("===) 1 newsVC.count : \(newsViewControllers.count)")
newsViewControllers.forEach { vc in
     print("===) 2 newsVC = \(vc)")
}

print("===) 3 naviVC.viewControllers.count : \(navigationController.viewControllers.count)")
print("===) 4 newsVC.count : \(newsViewControllers.count)")

navigationController.viewControllers = newsViewControllers //Problem here: set newsVCs not work!!!!!!
//naviVC.setViewControllers(newsVCs, animated: false)
            
print("===) 5 naviVC.viewControllers.count : \(navigationController.viewControllers.count)")
navigationController.viewControllers.forEach { vc in
    print("===) 6 vcvc: \(vc)")
}
```

Output:

```
===) 1 newsVC.count : 2
===) 2 newsVC = <UIViewController: 0x7fdeeb5114e0>
===) 2 newsVC = <UIViewController: 0x7fdeea705e00>
===) 3 naviVC.viewControllers.count : 1
===) 4 newsVC.count : 2
===) 5 naviVC.viewControllers.count : 2
===) 6 vcvc: <UIViewController: 0x7fdeeb5114e0>
===) 6 vcvc: <UIViewController: 0x7fdeea705e00>
```